# "gcloud auth print-access-token" to get refresh token runs slow on my mac os-x

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

For our project, we use google cloud container registry (gcr.io) to push all our container images.
We have our build system that tries to pull the base images from the container registry.

To pull the container image from the registry we do that using oauth2 access token mechanism and the build script runs the "gcloud auth print-access-token" command to get the access token.

Following is the sample run for `gloud --verbosity=debug auth print-access-token`,

```
$ date;gcloud --verbosity=debug auth print-access-token;date
Fri Jul 17 10:23:57 PDT 2020
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.auth.print-access-token] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
< -- Get stuck here for 2 minutes -- >

DEBUG: Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
INFO: Display format: "value(token)"
<Output Token Here>
Fri Jul 17 10:25:58 PDT 2020
```

Output from the `gcloud config list`

```
[core]
account = <email address>
disable_usage_reporting = False
log_http_redact_token = False
project = <project-id>

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

After looking at the code for Google SDK i found out that the Google SDK is trying to make a http call to `http://google.metadata.internal` every 10 minutes and hence it gets stuck finishing those calls since these calls will get resolved only from internal Google Compute instances.

Questions:

- Is it expected that the `gcloud` tool is making the calls to google internal DNS when i run the utility from my MacBook? ( I am new to GCP so i am ready to share more information about my config if needed )
- Is there a way to avoid the calls to google internal DNS for `gcloud auth print-access-token` commands ?
- If there is no way to avoid the calls(eventhough it fails from my Mac), is there a way to reduce the time-outs for the calls to google's internal DNS or is there a way to not do it every 10 minutes ?

Comment: Another command you may use is `gcloud ... --log-http` which is similar and would help show whether the `debug` flag is your issue. When I `print-access-token` the command completes almost immediately. Because I'm off-cloud, curl'ing `google.metadata.internal` fails quickly too. I wonder whether you've some other problem that's triggering this behavior. I'm using a Linux machine and `gcloud` 301.0.0. Have you tried a non-OSX machine?

Comment: You may also use [`oauth2l`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) to grab access tokens.

Comment: Great Answer @DazWilkin ..